# NFC Tag caught by android's default Tag Viewer instead of app

Tags: android, nfc

I've followed differents tutorials and read some fix related to that issue and still, nothing seems to work... Whenever I scan a NFC tag, it opens the default android app called *Tag Viewer* telling me "**New tag collected**" and with the body "**Empty tag**" and nothing happens within my app. I can't get any log printed...

Here is my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activityv2.ActivityHome"
        android:label="Home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tag_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Here is my Activity:

```
public class ActivityHome extends GenericActivity implements BackHandledFragment.BackHandlerInterface, OnFragmentListener {

    private final String TAG = "ActivityHome";


    public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";


    @Bind(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.actionToolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.left_drawer_item)
    LinearLayout mDrawerLinear;
    @Bind(R.id.left_drawer_child)
    ListView mDrawerListChild;
    @Bind(R.id.profil_pic)
    CircleImageView mProfilPic;
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_v2_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer


        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }


    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

            String type = intent.getType();
            if (MIME_TEXT_PLAIN.equals(type)) {

                Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Wrong mime type: " + type);
            }
        } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

            // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
            String searchedTech = Ndef.class.getName();

            for (String tech : techList) {
                if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
                    new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        /**
         * This method gets called, when a new Intent gets associated with the current activity instance.
         * Instead of creating a new activity, onNewIntent will be called. For more information have a look
         * at the documentation.
         *
         * In our case this method gets called, when the user attaches a Tag to the device.
         */
        handleIntent(intent);
    }


    private class NdefReaderTask extends AsyncTask<Tag, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Tag... params) {
            Tag tag = params[0];

            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef == null) {
                // NDEF is not supported by this Tag.
                return null;
            }

            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();

            NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
            for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
                if (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(ndefRecord.getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
                    try {
                        return readText(ndefRecord);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported Encoding", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        private String readText(NdefRecord record) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        /*
         * See NFC forum specification for "Text Record Type Definition" at 3.2.1
         *
         * http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/
         *
         * bit_7 defines encoding
         * bit_6 reserved for future use, must be 0
         * bit_5..0 length of IANA language code
         */

            byte[] payload = record.getPayload();

            // Get the Text Encoding
            String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";

            // Get the Language Code
            int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

            // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");
            // e.g. "en"

            // Get the Text
            return new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, result);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mNfcAdapter != null)
            stopForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mNfcAdapter != null)
            setupForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().removeOnBackStackChangedListener(mOnBackStackChangedListener);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
        String[][] techList = new String[][]{};

        // Notice that this is the same filter as in our manifest.
        filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
        filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        try {
            filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
        } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Check your mime type.");
        }

        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
    }

    public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
    }

}
```

Here is the XML config to catch them all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

And the message I get when I go near a tag and the default tag viewer opens:

```
04-20 12:45:26.825 799-2511/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.android.nfc/.NfcRootActivity (has extras)} from uid 1027 on display 0
04-20 12:45:26.874 1952-24878/? D/NativeNfcTag: Starting background presence check
04-20 12:45:26.913 1952-4642/? W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 16000 Hz, output 48000 Hz
04-20 12:45:26.917 799-24452/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED cmp=com.google.android.tag/com.android.apps.tag.TagViewer (has extras)} from uid 1027 on display 0
04-20 12:45:26.947 799-1287/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 24893:com.google.android.tag/u0a18 for activity com.google.android.tag/com.android.apps.tag.TagViewer
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Android Activity when NFC\_TECH is discovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794021/open-android-activity-when-nfc-tech-is-discovered)

Comment: You might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/33060923/2425802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I foudn the solution from @tatianag :

In first time I read a tutorial about nfc and I use some part of the code. And there was some code that I had not adapted to the advice you gave me.

This is the old part of my code

```
IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
try {
    filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
} catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
    Log.e("App","Wrong mime")
}
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
```

Wrong action, mime type. Many errors... I change for

```
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, null, null);
```

And it works perfectly! I hope it can help someone like you helped me by your explanations.

Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Just would like to add that the PendingIntent needs to be mutable. As of SDK 31, this needs to be declared explicitly:

```
val mutabilityFlag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE else 0    
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, mutabilityFlag)
```